# Dropbox iOS API - Simple Questions / DBRestClient Problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

**EDIT:**

I think I have fixed my issues.  Thank you for the help - I really appreciate it.

---

**Original Question:**

I am new to objective-c and iOS programming, so hopefully my issues are not difficult to correct.  I am trying to add the ability to open a file from Dropbox to my simple iOS application.  I have been following the tutorial here:

http://www.mathiastauber.com/integration-of-dropbox-in-your-ios-application-making-api-calls/

I have so far successfully gotten my app to link to my Dropbox account and display the "link successful" message.

Now I am having trouble using the DBRestClient.  I have the following code currently:

myviewcontroller.h

```
...
@end
DBRestClient *restClient;
```

myviewcontroller.m

```
- (DBRestClient *)restClient {
    if (!restClient) {
        restClient =
        [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return restClient;
}
```

I am getting an error on the line

```
restClient.delegate = self;
```

that says 
`"Assigning to 'id<DBRestClientDelegate>' from incompatible type 'myviewcontroller'"`

What could be going wrong?  I have read through every example I can find and can see no issues with what I am trying to do.

If I try to cast by doing the following, it does not work

```
restClient.delegate = (id)self;
```

I have also found that if I remove the code in myviewcontroller.m and only have the variable declaration in the header file (as shown above) I get an error that says "Apple Mach-O Linker Error"

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.  I am very much stuck with this problem.

Comment: Can update your question to show the interface declaration that's at the top of your header (myviewcontroller.h) file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your header file you need to specify that you adhere to the `DBRestClientDelegate`'s *protocol*.

For example:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <DBRestClientDelegate>
```

If you're already adhering to other protocols, simply add the DBRestClientDelegate and comma seperate, such as...

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, DBRestClientDelegate>
```

For more information, I'd recommend a read of the Delegation section of [Cocoa Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html), especially as you'll be encountering delegates (and indeed perhaps defining your own protocols, etc.) a lot in Cocoa.

Comment: Don't add this to the .h file. Add it to a class extension in the .m file. No need to tell the world that the class has this implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the right side of `restClient.delegate = self;` is not of type `id<DBRestClientDelegate>`

`id<DBRestClientDelegate>` is basically any object that conforms to the `DBRestClientDelegate` protocol

The first step (maybe only step) to removing the error is in your Myviewcontroller.h file

change

```
@interface Myviewcontroller : UIViewController   //<-- my best guess at your interface line
```

to

```
@interface Myviewcontroller : UIViewController <DBRestClientDelegate>
```

Comment: I made the change and am now encountering the error "Apple Mach-O Linker Error."  If I move the DBRestClient *restClient declaration to be a global in my .m file instead, I get the error " DropboxSDK: cannot initialize a DBRestClient with a nil session" printed to the console.  Am I not placing the declaration in the right place?